# I observe the following stack trace when I try to start my jboss server (from both eclipse IDE and the standalone.sh from my unix terminal):)

Tags: exception, jboss, persistence, jboss7.x, stax

I observe the following stack trace when I try to start my jboss server (from both eclipse IDE and the standalone.sh from my unix terminal). Could anybody please tell why?:

```
JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

16:41:48,878 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
16:41:49,025 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
16:41:49,066 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
16:41:49,289 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05-icedtea]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2104)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2010)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1102)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1125)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:67) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 3 more

16:41:49,295 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
16:41:49,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 1ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the relevant lines

```
JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
```

Looks like you're missing a configuration file (or more likely it's empty).

Comment: Strangely it was neiother missing nor empty! It seemed later that it was probably because of a disk space error that it wasnt even able to perform the read operation on the file!!

Answer (score 4):

This means that there is some problem with your Standalone.xml. Take a fresh one, it should work.

Comment: +1 .. my standalone.xml file was empty.  I had replaced an xml file inside of the standalone/deploy/ folder, and it had a bad MSSQL connection string, and JBoss never booted properly.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same problem and found out that **standalone.xml was empty**.

I don't know what could have caused this though...  U can find back up of ur standalone.xml in ${AS7_installation}/standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history